# Fibonacci sequence, public static void xxx

Tags: fibonacci

I'm just a very beginner and need for help with Fibonacci sequence. So the problem is that I need to ask a number from the answerer and secondly print the Fibonacci number that fits with the answerer's number?  Is the method that I need to use "public static void xxx" loop?
I hope someone understands my bad English and can help me with my problem.

Comment: There is no code here.  Did you write any?

Comment: Hey. No I did not sent any code. There is just my question.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need it in java:

```java
    import java.io.*;
    public class Fibonacci{
        // your method public static void xxx
        public static void fib() throws IOException 
        {
            // take input from user
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            // compute nth fibonacci: your loop
            int f1 = 0, f2 = 1;
            if(n == 0)
             System.out.println(f1);
            for(int i=2; i<n; i++)
            {
               int fi = f1 + f2;
               f1 = f2;
               f2 = fi;
            }
           // print your answer
           System.out.println(f2);
        }
        public static void main(Strings args[])
        {
            // call fib method
            fib();
        } 
    }
```